# Kitchen sink border rotting

Tags: wood, kitchens, sink, mold, trim

The rear border of my kitchen sink is slowly rotting from years of water splashing, to the point there is warping & veneer detachment. Attempted to reseal years ago (note white caulking), but it is now beyond simple cosmetic patching. Particle board undersurface very spongy, with obvious black mold growth. Without complete rebuild, interested in some solutions. Me: handy, but not a handyman.
[image: Sink pics]

Comment: Without a complete rebuild, it doesn't get fixed, period. You're long past the band-aid phase.

Comment: Your soap ledge has the same issue...

Answer (score 4):

The countertop need to be replaced. Period. There is no repair that is not anything other than a waste of time and money.

The cabinetry may need replacing as well.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you can't afford a new counter - if possible you might find a new-to-you counter at a Habitat restore or construction recycling store. You're going to need to replace it before it spreads and at the very least stop using it and put a fan under the sink to dry out what's already rotten while attempting to be mindful of spreading the mold elsewhere.

I'm in a similar boat and can't afford a new one. People get rid of these when they do remodels, etc. You want to address this before you wind up needing to replace more than the counter - if not already as RMDman said.

Comment: Yup - can often get a new countertop complete with sink, sometimes faucet as well for not much. Luck of the draw, of course, depending what's on hand that day.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem of spongy wood, but no visible mold.I found a product called PC-Petrifier which was around $20. I first made some small holes for the liquid and used a paint brush to ensure it got under the veneer. I went over it many times to make sure I got enough in to saturate. That old rotting particle board is now rock solid! I finished by sealing the holes with silicone. The faucet still has some slight movement, but nothing like it was. In your case because of the mold you should probably saturate with peroxide or vinegar first.